# The Command "composer require maatwebsite/excel" doesnt works

Tags: laravel, installation, failed-installation, maatwebsite-excel

Im trying to run the command: "composer require maatwebsite/excel

" in the Laravel Terminal to use PhpSpreadSheet, but I get the following error: installation failed, reverting ./composer.json...." any idea how to solve the problem, regards. Amaury

Comment: Please show the error detail.

Comment: Please include the error details with the command line output also details about your setup laravel version php etc. could be useful.